# Array method that does nothing

Tags: javascript, arrays

I like functional programming, it keeps my code, especially scopes, cleaner.

I found myself having a pretty heavy Array manipulation in my code, like this:

```
this.myArray = someArray
    .slice(0, n)
    .map(someFunction)
    // more manipulation;

if (condition) {
    this.myArray = this.myArray.reverse();
}

this.myArray = this.myArray
    .reduce(anotherFunction, [])
    // even more manipulation
```

Is there some built-in way to join the `if` to my functional chain? Something like:

```
this.myArray = someArray
    .slice(0, n)
    .map(someFunction)
    // ... more manipulation
    [condition ? 'reverse' : 'void']()
    .reduce(anotherFunction, [])
    // ... even more manipulation
```

The `void()` method doesn't exist. Is there an alternative? Is it popular approach to merge multiple calls to a single chain, even if that means calling methods that do nothing?

I know I can add my own method to Array:

```
Array.prototype.void = function () {
    return this;
}
```

But that's not the point. Is there any standard/built-in way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: I don't believe there is, maybe you'd want extend the prototype beforehand with a custom reverse function, where it checks the conditional there instead...?

Comment: You're already using `slice()` which does just that. Why not use it again?

Comment: Right...`slice()` with no args returns shallow copy of whole array

Comment: Just to play devils advocate. The example code you are trying to replace is clear and readable. And the example code you are trying to produce is going to risk being convoluted and unobvious.

Comment: @CooperBuckingham I partially agree, but if there was a method doing nothing, it would have been cleaner, wouldn't it? I think all built-in types should have a method doing nothing.

Comment: I guess I would just ask myself “what problem am I trying to solve”? It’s unlikely that the just in time compiler will be able to optimize those chained interactions into a stream. So you’re at best adding no overhead in the “fully chained” version, and at worst adding another 0(n) iteration. But adding a dynamic bracket notation property look up inside of a ternary expression, all just to avoid an external if block. Just typing it feels more complicated. You also take all power away from smart-ish IDEs to possibly detect errors, or to find usages of the methods in question.

Comment: I think that depends on a person. To me, writing conditional block, where I repeat entire variable name twice, is odd. I really like to minimize the number of repetition when it comes to names. Functional paradigm is neat, it does its job and leaves no garbage behind. You know, I ask this question mostly for educational purpose, but I really had this situation recently where I manipulated array heavily and needed to have one conditional manipulation in the middle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As neutral function, you could take

- [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), which returns a new array with old items, or
- [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), which returns as well a new array.

Comment: The best answer so far. I'm glad you understand my question.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Looks like `concat()` is the way to go, I don't care about the slight performance cost of recreating the array.

Comment: @RoboRobok - Actually, `slice` is probably the better choice.

Comment: Is there any real performance difference? `concat` is a little more readable, as "add nothing".

Comment: @RoboRobok - Whatever floats your boat, you're already not worrying about performance or you'd add `void` and return the same array. :-) I wouldn't expect a significant difference, no, since `concat` only has to do its extra check (whether it needs to spread something out) on its arguments, not on the contents of the array you call it on, and you're not giving it any arguments. :-)

Comment: I mean I do worry about the performance where it makes a difference, but I'm not into micro optimization in JS most of the time, as it really doesn't give anything but mental comfort.

Comment: I guess another way to do it is with using either `reduce` or `reduceRight` and do `method((acc, item) => acc.concat(item), [])` so, you'd get either the same array or the array reversed back.

Comment: Guys, I just learned to use `console.time(?label)` today and in Chrome, `concat()` is about **12** times slower than `slice()`! It's really fascinating!

Comment: And in Firefox, `concat()` is about 10% **faster**. Crazy! :D

Answer (score 4):

> Is it popular approach to merge multiple calls to a single chain, even if that means calling methods that do nothing?

No. The usual approach is to split the chain, similar to how you wrote it in your first snippet, when there is an optional step. You wouldn't however repeatedly assign to `this.myArray`, you would use *constant* temporary variables:

```
const array1 = someArray.slice(0, n).map(someFunction) // more manipulation;
const array2 = condition ? array1.reverse() : array1;
this.myArray = array2.reduce(anotherFunction, []) // even more manipulation
```

That said, in functional programming that uses functions, not methods, you sometimes do find the approach of having a configurable chain. They don't need a `void` method on the object, they just use the `identity` function.

Example in Haskell:

```hs
let maybeReverse = if condition then reverse else identity
let myArray = fold anotherFunction [] $ maybeReverse $ map someFunction $ take n someArray
```

Example in JavaScript (where you don't have as many useful builtins and need to write them yourself):

```
const fold = (fn, acc, arr) => arr.reduce(fn, acc);
const reverse = arr => arr.reverse(); // add .slice() to make pure
const identity = x => x;
const map = (fn, arr) => arr.map(fn);
const take = (n, arr) => arr.slice(0, n);

const maybeReverse = condition ? reverse : identity;
const myArray = fold(anotherFunction, [], maybeReverse(map(someFunction, take(n, someArray)))));
```

---

Btw, in your particular example I wouldn't use `reverse` at all, but rather conditionally switch between `reduce` and `reduceRight` :-)

Comment: I'm not sure if I like this approach. You end up having two arrays, like how would you name them for the code to make sense? What if I have more of these conditional changes?

Comment: @RoboRobok call them `arr1` and `arr2`? Or whatever makes sense - you could go with `partialResult` and `result`, if you wish. I don't think it really matters that much. And if you have more conditional changes then *maybe* you should split that function as it seems to be doing too much. But if it still makes sense to have it as one, just do `partialResult1` and then `partialResult2`. I think you are overthinking this.

Comment: @RoboRobok it depends on the code of course how you'd name them descriptively - or just go for `tempN`. And if you had many of these conditionals, it might be worth it to duplicate the entire chain and adapt it to the respective case.

Comment: @Bergi Well, if I'm about to use `varN` names, I would reconsider using functional paradigm in the first place.

Comment: @RoboRobok In completely abstract functions (like where your parameters are named `xs` and `ys`, `f` and `g` etc), that's often the best you got. In a concrete function you would of course use concrete variable names.

Comment: If *variables* make you dislike FP, then perhaps you really need to include functors, monads, and applicatives in your code, as well as FP styled functions, so you can go pointer-free.

Comment: "If variables make you dislike FP" - this statement doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You said, you don't like having a trivial variable called `varN` in functional code. If you don't like temporary variables, then I'm suggesting pointer-free code with constructs that save you from having to assign intermediate results to a variable.

Comment: I don't like having temporary variables in any form of code, avoiding them is a good practice in my book. Especially when they are meaningless, just being the same thing under condition. "If you can't find a proper name for it, it's probably bad."

Comment: @RoboRobok If you're looking for point-free style (no variables/parameters), then you cannot use method chains and will have to use plain functions instead. You can start by making two helper functions `reverse` and `identity`.

Comment: @Bergi not sure if I understand what you mean. How is creating a `reverse()` function different? And what is `identity()` function about? I actually like the answers with `slice()` and `concat()`. In some frameworks, I have seen methods performing manipulation based on condition, like `.when(condition, function () {})`, which turns the chain to whatever. I really like these, I'm into S&M in programming, I like chains :D

Comment: OK, so again - use FP constructs that avoid variables. A simple identity functor allows you to do all the manipulations without breaking a chain for an optional operation. You might even have a functor that does an optional `reverse` on mapping, according to some condition. But with an identity functor to reverse or not you'd do `functor.map(reverse)` or `functor.map(identity)` which you can decide before the chain starts by a simple `operation = condition ? reverse : identity`, then you'd do `functor.map(arr => arr.map(someFunction)).map(operation).map(arr => arr.reduce(anotherFunction))`.

Comment: @RoboRobok Methods and method chains are not as composable as plain functions. See my updated answer. You can inline any of the helper variables, but the result won't be as readable.

Comment: @Bergi There is no readability whatsoever in that. No me gusta.

Comment: A `compose` (ore `pipe`/`flow` which goes left to right) would make it more readable. But I agree, this is more actual functional code. I actually like it, myself.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to switch `reduce()` with [`reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) which wouldn't add an extra step at all for the case shown

```
this.myArray = someArray
    .slice(0, n)
    .map(someFunction)   
    [condition ? 'reduce' : 'reduceRight'](anotherFunction, [])
```

Comment: Just commented something similar - but you can use `reduce` or `reduceRight` to return the array or a reversed array if you pass in `(acc, item) => acc.concat(item)` and `[]` as parameters to it. This way, it doesn't matter what the next thing in the chain is, or even *if* there is one.

Comment: Interesting, but keep in mind it's `reverse()` here that's optional, not `reduce()`.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to be explicit about reversing, not covering it up with an alternative. I'm pretty sure there are multiple practical ways to achieve the effect I'm looking for, but let's also respect code readability.